# How to use API result as the property of the object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await

I am making a a one page web app with JavaScript and TypeScript. I am also using the module system of JavaScript (`type="module"`).

I have a class called `Form` that takes in an object and creates a `Form`. I have a module in which I have all the data for Registration form. There is one select in the inputs which have options field. I was those options to be assigned to the array containing names of countries. I am using an API to get the names of the countries. But I am stuck.

Below is my file `RegisterFormDialog.ts`

```
const RegisterFormData: IForm = {
   //... Some other props
   inputs: [
      //..Some other objects.
      {
         name: "country",
         type: "select",
         label: "Country",
         options: countries.map(x => x.name) // Here I want result of the api
      }
   ]
};

export const RegisterForm = new Form(RegisterFormData);

export const RegisterFormDialog = new Dialog({
   child: RegisterForm.element,
   title: "Register",
   dismissable: true,
   onClose: () => 5,
   parentElement: qs("#main") as HTMLElement
});
```

The other file is which have the API function. Its name is `GetCountries.ts`

```
export default async function getCountries() {
   return await (await fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")).json();
}
```

Now how could I assign the returned value of the data of API to the options property in the object.

Comment: It's not clear how any of what you're showing fits together. `this.options = await getCountries()`, maybe? Give a [mcve].

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yeah this `this.options = await getCountries()` i closest to my need. But problem is I can't use `await` without `async`

Comment: Correct, because it's really just a promise, *something* needs to resolve it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe So does this mean that if I want this api data inside here I will have change the whole code structure?

Comment: That's the deal, yes.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Isn't there any alternative?

Comment: Observables? Callbacks? See the canonical https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/3001761. If you're not comfortable with async you probably don't want to be writing your own SPA framework.

Comment: @MaheerAli You need an asynchronous result, it's not possible to grab that and bring it into a fully synchronous context where you can immediately export and have it available synchronously to the rest of your code. If your options depend on a network request, then all code depending on the options is now asynchronous as it can't run until the network request finishes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

Any function declared as `async` should be `awaited` (or use `.then()`) to use its resolved value.

So you just have to `await` your `getCountries` function, too.

```
options: (await getCountries).map(x => x.name)
```

Comment: Its giving error. `'await' expression is only allowed within an async function.ts(1308)`

Comment: Yep. Any function that awaits an async function, must also (logically) be async. So that error tells you everything you need to know here.

Comment: Top-level await is still in the proposal stage, is it not? This is clearly in the top level from the use of `export`, making one of the variables depended on by the `export` async seems problematic. You'll have to import and resolve a promise to do things this way, per the other answer @MaheerAli